How to interpret the product of POVM elements?
Suppose $m\not=n$, and fix a state $|\psi\rangle$. If $\\{P_k\\}$ defines a PVM, then we have $\langle \psi|P_n P_m|\psi \rangle = 0$. Physically, this makes sense, as one cannot obtain two different measurement results $m$ and $n$ in a single measurement, and $P_n P_m$ projects onto the space in which both $n$ and $m$ are simultaneously properties of the states in the space. Mathematically, it makes sense that the expectation value is $0$, as $P_n P_m = 0$.
My question is how this generalizes to POVMs. If $\\{E_k\\}$ defines a POVM, then can we say anything about $\langle \psi|E_n E_m |\psi \rangle$? On the one hand, I would expect that $\langle \psi|E_n E_m |\psi \rangle = 0$, since one cannot obtain two different measurement results in a single measurement, and $p(n) = \langle \psi|E_n|\psi\rangle$. On the other hand, I don't see how to prove this from the $\sum_k E_k = 1$ and $E_k \geq 0$ properties.

You can easily cook up counterexamples which give pretty much any value you want (or don't want), including complex ones.

No, You can have the POVM $E_i =\frac{ \mathbb{I}}{n}$. This set of POVM effectively throws away the state and picks a random number between 1 and n. But we do have the property $\langle\psi|E_iE_j|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{n^2}$.
